# Clojure - how to do reductions function but drop state?

Tags: clojure, reduce

If I use the reductions function like so:

```
(reductions + [1 2 3 4 5])
```

Then I get

```
(1 3 6 10 15)
```

Which is great - but I'd like to apply a binary function in the same way without the state being carried forward - something like

```
(magic-hof + [1 2 3 4 5])
```

leads to

```
(1 3 5 7 9)
```

ie it returns the operation applied to the first pair, then steps 1 to the next pair.

Can someone tell me the higher-order function I'm looking for? (Something like reductions)

This is my (non-working) go at it:

```
(defn thisfunc [a b] [(+ a b) b])

(reduce thisfunc [1 2 3 4 5])
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it with map:

```
(map f coll (rest coll))
```

And if you want a function:

```
(defn map-pairwise [f coll]
  (map f coll (rest coll)))
```

And if you really need the first element to remain untouched (thanx to [juan.facorro's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20611577/clojure-how-to-do-reductions-function-but-drop-state#comment-30844457)):

```
(defn magic-hof [f [x & xs :as s]]
  (cons x (map f s xs)))
```

Comment: I think the first element would be missing from the result :). Maybe `(defn magic-hof [f [x & xs :as s]] (conj (map f s xs) x))`?

Comment: The `magic-hof`version cannot handle empty seqs correctly: `(magic-hof + [])` => `(nil)`. But then again, that depends on the meaning of "correctly" here. ;)

Comment: Perhaps, `(defn magic [f s] (map f (list* (f) s) s))` for some `f`s.

Comment: @A.Webb not all two variable functions support `(f)` call.

Comment: No, thus "some", but to mimic the behavior of reductions `(f)` should be returned when called on an empty collection, something which my "perhaps" function fails to do as well. Conciseness will have to give way a bit if that behavior is desired.

Comment: So with (magic-hof + (range 1 6)) I get (1 3 5 7 9) - nice. Thanks for putting so much thought into this answer.

Answer (score 5):

`partition` will group your seq:

```
user> (->> [1 2 3 4 5] (partition 2 1) (map #(apply + %)) (cons 1))
(1 3 5 7 9)
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to apply a function to subsequent pairs of elements?

```
(defn pairwise-apply
  [f sq]
  (when (seq sq)
    (->> (map f sq (next sq))
         (cons (first sq)))))
```

Let's try it:

```
(pairwise-apply + (range 1 6))
;; => (1 3 5 7 9)
```

Comment: This is nice in that it just operates on one version of the list.

Answer (score 0):

This is sufficient:

```
(#(map + (cons 0 %) %) [1 2 3 4 5])
;; => (1 3 5 7 9)
```

Comment: The simplicity of this is nice.